# Angularstrap Datepicker setting previous date in ngmodel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular strap library for datepicker. When I select any date from the calendar, previous date is set in the ngmodel.

[image]

If date is set as default to the input the date is set properly.

[image]

```
$scope.pickerDateTime2 = new Date();
$scope.pickerChange = function () {
  var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
  var name = tz.name();

  $scope.dateTimeUtc = ngmTimeCalc.convertFromPicker($scope.pickerDateTime2, name);
}

$scope.reloadPicker=function(){
  $scope.pickerChange();
  var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client
  var name = tz.name();

  $scope.pickerDateTime2 = ngmTimeCalc.convertToPicker($scope.dateTimeUtc, name);
```

}

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/KjEtU99clbxZGZwDvHAC?p=preview

How can I set correct date when the user chooses from the calendar

Comment: Seem like it's a bug of Angular strap, I got the same error in the demo page. You can report the bug here to get it fixed: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: This isn't a bug but it needs some other change to get it working. Same issue is present even in HTML5 date picker.